# Average no. of objects in a box,when m objects are filled in n boxes.$(m>n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The formula for the average no. of objects in a box,when m objects are filled in n boxes $(m>n)$

is given by $[m/n]$ ,if $(m/n)\in \mathbb Z$

and $[m/n]+1$,if $(m/n)\notin \mathbb Z$ .

The thing I can't understand is why in the second case did we take $[m/n]+1$ and not $[m/n]$.

Answer (score 1):

This formula is incorrect.  For example, if $m=6$, $n=5$, then perhaps four boxes have one object and one box has two objects.  However $[m/n]+1=2$, so the "average no." is $2$.

The correct formula is $m/n$, with no floors, and no plus one, assuming "average" means "[mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean)".